# how to insert an URL in android email

Tags: android, email, url

From my app i want to share some detail via email and all other sites. Following is my code to open email

```
private void email() 
{
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
  i.setType("message/rfc822") ;
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{""});  
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,i0+" hiiiiiiiiii");  
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,**sharetext**);  
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select application"));
}
```

Following is my sharetext

"hi friends please visit my website for http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/apply "

Now i want the url in my share text to be viewed in a blue line, so that when the user clicks it i want to open the webpage.

But in my app the url seems to be normal one. How to do this....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `SpannableStringBuilder` to build text with embedded url link. Here is an example:

```
private void email() 
{
    String url = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/apply";

    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append("hi friends please visit my website for");
    int start = builder.length();
    builder.append(url);
    int end = builder.length();

    builder.setSpan(new URLSpan(url), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
    i.setType("message/rfc822") ;
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{""});  
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"hiiiiiiiiii");  
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, builder);  
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select application"));
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: hi thanx for your answer. If i want to add the url in between of the text such as hi friends please visit my website for http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/apply and you can get..............." how can i do it.....