# How to send a URL in email using Android Intents

Tags: android, email, android-intent, html-email

I'm trying to send a market URL (for eg- market://details?id=com.android.chrome) to a helper app in an email using Intents. I tried using SpannableStringbuilder to ember the URL as proposed in [Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369060/how-to-insert-an-url-in-android-email) and I also tried to use Html.fromHtml as proposed in [this blog post](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2010/05/17/sending-html-email-with-android-intent/)

In both the cases, I'm able to send the email but email received does not have any URL. while sending the email I use Gmail as the application for sending the email.

It seems like both the options were proposed a few years ago. Is there a more current way to do this ?

thanks

Comment: Is there a certain reason for you to use email to send the link? Is it just the url that is missing from the email the helper app receives?

Comment: You can send the URL as simple text, using Intent.EXTRA_TEXT extra

Comment: So, the usage is similar to "download app" URLs in emails. Most these URL's get redirected to a server and then eventually can be consumed by play store application to show the app to be downloaded. We are trying to avoid the external server assuming that such a URL when invoked can be intercepted by play store because of schema. If there is a better strategy, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not if sure if I'm drifting away from your exact question but can you try something like the following: http://danielmuller.asia/2013/02/android-open-an-app-from-web-link-or-fallback-to-market/ (under "Fallback to market if app is not installed"). It might not solve your issue but you might get an idea from it?

Comment: That actually helped a lot and I ended up working out an alternative solution. Thanks a lot :)